# Is fuel pellets a cylinder shape to decrease the critical mass?

Tags: nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering

A cylinder, especially a thin rod is a terrible configuration to have a self sustaining nuclear chain reaction. Cylinder pellets are used in nuclear reactors.

[image]

A sphere is a much better packed configuration, where less neutrons leave the material. Such as the pit in an atomic device.

[image]

I wonder, if the design of nuclear pellets specifically choose a cylinder shape to decrease the critical mass? Or is it more a technical solution, i.e. better stack-able in the rector design? I think it might have to do with a safety consideration, but I was not able to find a source for this.

Comment: Why does it matter if neutrons leave one pellet if they have a high probability of encountering another pellet?

Comment: As that a fact? That they will have a high probability of encountering another pellet?

Comment: A nuclear reactor wants to be just barely critical, and stay barely critical. And it wants lots of moderated, thermal neutrons since they have the highest cross section for initiating fission. One wants the ~2MeV neutrons generated from fission to transit the water to thermalize them.

Comment: It isn't the same, but similar considerations are important for the design of nuclear weapons. For more on that, see Scott Manley's series, [Going Nuclear](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLYu7z3I8tdEnTQMXpP6gYN9DVm_DjXza9). He also has episodes on reactor design. You might find answers in episode 8, [Why Chernobyl Exploded - The Real Physics Behind The Reactor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q3d3rzFTrLg&list=PLYu7z3I8tdEnTQMXpP6gYN9DVm_DjXza9&index=9).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that a tall skinny cylinder is a terrible configuration to keep critical, but you are only considering a single rod.  You have to consider the entire core, which takes the shape of a larger cylinder where the height is approximately equal to the diameter.  While this shape isn't as good for criticality, it is pretty good.

The reason for using a cylinder instead of a sphere is that you have to remove the heat from the reactor, and to do that it is useful to have the axial direction uniform so water (or some other coolant) can flow from the bottom to the top and transport the heat from the fuel.  If the core was spherical, it would be difficult to come up with a way to transport the heat from the core efficiently.  The limiting factor in reactor design is often the peak cladding temperature, so you want a geometry that allows the heat to be conducted efficiently.

Answer (score 5):

The fuel pellet heats up, this is the basis for the operation of the nuclear reactor.
To evacuate the heat produced ( more than  4000 MW  thermal for some of them ) , you must divide the fuel mass to have a  large surface area in contact with the water (if we are talking about water reactors ).
The fuel pellet must never reach its melting temperature, otherwise it is a serious accident.
In a PWR , fuel pellet center temperature is around  1100 °C  in nominal conditions .
UO2  fuel pellet fuses at 2600 °C  .

Comment: UO2 is a ceramic material and has very poor heat conductivity – as you said the center temperature is 1100 °C as compared to the coolant temperature of less than 300 °C. So there's a temperature gradient of 800 °C within the 5 mm radius of the pellet!